# Xamarin Grid columns with dynamic width: object occupies the wrong column despite assignment

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am attempting to create a grid in Xamarin forms with two columns that each take up half of the screen. I have implemented my XAML as follows

```xml
<Grid VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#3F4045" Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#3F4045"/>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start">
            <Frame BackgroundColor="#FCFCFC" CornerRadius="0" Margin="0" Padding="0">
                <Entry TextColor="#3F4045" BackgroundColor="#FCFCFC" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" PlaceholderColor="#3F4045" Placeholder="Last Name, First Name"/>
            </Frame>
         </Grid>
         <Grid Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Start">
             <Frame BackgroundColor="#FCFCFC" CornerRadius="0" Margin="0" Padding="0">
                 <Button TextColor="#3F4045" BackgroundColor="#FCFCFC" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="Upload Records"/>
             </Frame>
         </Grid>
     </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The two frames are supposed to each take up half of the second row with a small amount of space between them. However, when the app loads, they each take up half of the first column with a small amount of space between them. I experimented by changing the width of the second column from 5* to 8* and, as I expected, both of the frames shrunk so together they took up 5/13 of the screen, meaning that they are actually both in the first column. Here are pictures of the problem and the test I did with widths 5* and 8* for reference:

[image: Picture demonstrating that both frames occupy the half of the first column instead of each appearing in their own column][image: Picture demonstrating that both frames are definitely in the same column]

Is there something I'm missing in setting Horizontal/VerticalOptions in the frames or grid tags? Thank you for the help!

Comment: why are your Frames both nested inside of child grids instead of being children of the main grid?

Comment: Haha this actually turned out to be the answer. I thought using grid tags in that way with Grid.Row and Grid.Column referenced the parent grid's row and column definitions and was a way of assigning children to those rows and columns. It seemed to work for the other page of my app where I did the same thing and got the layout I wanted, but now I'm going to go back and reassess. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was removing the frames from the Grid tags and making them children of the parent grid directly, using Grid.Row and Grid.Column to assign them to the proper locations.

```xml
<Grid VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#3F4045" Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#3F4045"/>
    <Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="#FCFCFC" CornerRadius="0" Margin="0" Padding="0">
        <Entry TextColor="#3F4045" BackgroundColor="#FCFCFC" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" PlaceholderColor="#3F4045" Placeholder="Last Name, First Name"/>
    </Frame>
    <Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="#FCFCFC" CornerRadius="0" Margin="0" Padding="0">
        <Button TextColor="#3F4045" BackgroundColor="#FCFCFC" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="Upload Records"/>
    </Frame>
</Grid>
```

Here is the updated code.